# Rx 2 Android what is better Single or Observable for api calls?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

when we use retrofit2 for doing API rest calls with Rx, What is the best approach to use, Single or Observable?

```
public interface ApiService{

Single<Data> getDataFromServer();

Observable<Data> getDataFromServer();
}
```

Comment: If I had to choose I would use  Single,

Comment: Thanks, I agree with that as we only consume one element, however I'd like to get more feedback about choosing one or another.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd suggest using a `Single` as it is more accurate representation of the data flow: you make a request to the server and the you get either one emission of data **OR** an error:

```
Single:     onSubscribe (onSuccess | onError)?
```

For an `Observable` you could theoretically get several emissions of data **AND** an error

```
Observable: onSubscribe onNext? (onCompleted | onError)?
```

---

However, if you are using [rx-java2](/questions/tagged/rx-java2), I'd suggest using a [`Maybe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#maybe) instead of `Single`. The difference between those two is that `Maybe` handles also the case when you get the response from server but it contains no body.

```
Maybe:      onSubscribe (onSuccess | onCompleted | onError)?
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know anything about "maybe", seems an important element to keep in mind. FYI: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#maybe

Comment: Yeah, it's quite new, more like *for future reference*. Also FYI: https://medium.com/@manuelvicnt/rxjava2-android-mvvm-lifecycle-app-structure-with-retrofit-2-cf903849f49e

Answer (score 11):

Difference between `Observable` and `Single` is rather semantic. When you are declaring something `Single` you are saying that this observable is going to produce only one value, not series of values.

Using proper semantic types is the best way to document your API.

Comment: Wouldn't it correspond more to single response, not single object?