# Observable to list in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, observable

I have a service like this

```
 @GET("/")
fun getInfo(@Query("pew") pew1: Double, @Query("pew2") pew2: Double): Observable<PewResponse>
```

So now, when I have this

I have a List to fill with server data

```
private var mPewList: MutableList<PewList> = arrayListOf()
```

And then I have this function

```
override fun getResultFromNetwork(): Observable<PewResponse> {
    val pewObservable = pewService.getInfo("pew1","pew2")
    return pewObservable.concatMap {
      //How do I fill my list ??

    }


}
```

I'm pretty new to this `rxJava` so I saw people using `Single` and other guys using `Observable` what's better?

### EDIT

I'm following this example https://github.com/joanby/android-mvp/blob/master/MoviesFeed/app/src/main/java/com/juangabriel/moviesfeed/movies/MoviesRepository.java

And now I want to do something like this :

```
@Override
public Observable<Result> getResultFromNetwork() {

    Observable<TopMoviesRated> topMoviesRatedObservable = moviesApiService.getTopMoviesRated(1)
            /*.concatWith(moviesApiService.getTopMoviesRated(2))
            .concatWith(moviesApiService.getTopMoviesRated(3))*/;

    return topMoviesRatedObservable
            .concatMap(new Function<TopMoviesRated, Observable<Result>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Result> apply(TopMoviesRated topMoviesRated) {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(topMoviesRated.getResults());
                }
            }).doOnNext(new Consumer<Result>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Result result) {
                    results.add(result);
                }
            });

}
```

So as I'm seeing he fills the result list, and then on presenter do this : https://github.com/joanby/android-mvp/blob/master/MoviesFeed/app/src/main/java/com/juangabriel/moviesfeed/movies/MoviesPresenter.java

Comment: I don't understand how or why you want `mPewList` filled. Also why `concatMap` which is used to flatten a stream of observables of X into a stream of X? Is PewResponse observable? If not, you'll most likely want just `map` ("transform the items emitted by an Observable by applying a function to each item") I guess?

Comment: @zapl Please, see my edit, maybe it's more understandable now... sorry

Comment: Hm, that code is shady as well. `topMoviesRatedObservable.flatMapIterable(top -> top.getResults())` should do the same and make more sense than `concatMap`. And storing things in a `results` list sounds like a bad idea because it's probably not threadsafe.

Comment: @zapl So what should be a correct way? could you provide an answer following that github please?

Comment: @zapl Could you provide an alternative to this? Please I really need this

Comment: For the result of `getInfo` it probably makes sense to use `Single` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/41982370/995891 but otherwise, like p.alexey says, the logic in the very end shouln't be more than a) `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to have threadsafe access to the UI and then b) `.subscribe({ pewResponse -> mPewList = pewResponse./* something*/` to handle the result once available. Maybe `.subscribeWith(DisposableObserver(.. ` to get rid of the observable (e.g. https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data from server is monolithic you should to use `Single` because it return only once value. The `Observable` will do when your data arrives in chunks.

For more details you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42759432/9060113

**EDIT:**

```
@GET("/")
fun getInfo(@Query("pew") pew1: Double, @Query("pew2") pew2: Double): Single<PewResponse>


override fun getResultFromNetwork() {
  pewService
     .getInfo("pew1","pew2")
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // for background processing
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // get result in Main Thread (it require rxAndroid lib)
     .subscribe(
       { pewResponse -> // parse response and fill list },
       { // handle error }
     )
}
```

Comment: Ok, it's nice explained, but how do i fill my data?

Comment: I edited answer. You need to subscribe on your Single/Observable and parse you answer -> fill list.

Comment: But what I'm doing on my PresenterImpl is this, right? Because I need to do something like this, see my edit

Comment: Author from gitHub uses `concatMap` only for transform each `TopMoviesRated` to `List<Result>`. And then (in `MoviesModel`) he transform result `List<Result>` into ViewModel. Then presenter get this Observable, subscribes
on it and work with each ViewModel separately (in this case Observable is necessarily).

Comment: In my opinion this approach is very entangled. The data conversion logic is distributed across multiple entities (Repository and MoviesModel). I think that the data preparation logic should be concentrated in the Repository (or Interactor, if you use it). And your Presenter/Interactor already interacts this Repository and subscribes to Observable. Then in `onNext` callback your presenter gets piece of data and sent it to View for display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182245/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-p-alexey).

Comment: See the chat please